# Installer installed 2 Ubuntu entries - which one to boot into?

Tags: system-installation

I'm dual booting with Windows in UEFI. After installation, the Boot Manager added two Ubuntu entries:
"ubuntu (ST1000IM024 HM-M101MBV)", and "Ubuntu (ST1000IM024 HM-M101MBV)".

What is the difference between these 2?

I've not entered GRUB at this point.

Comment: With UEFI, the installer typically adds entries for both grub & shim. Where shim is the grub for secure boot. If secure boot is off, either should work. You can see which is grub or shim with this: `sudo efibootmgr -v` And you could change a description with efibootmgr if desired.  http://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that there are two bootable partitions in your system. Did you by any chance install the GRUB bootloader two times? If you don't know you can try to boot both of them. You can't destroy anything this way and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is "normal" if you installed Ubuntu with UEFI with **Secure Boot** enabled.

one is the normal boot loader, **Ubuntu (XXXXX)** and the other is the signed one, **ubuntu (XXXXX)**, you can see the diference one begin in Uppercase, the other one in lowercase.

for UEFI with secure boot enabled go with **ubuntu (XXXXX)**, the other one never launch because is not signed. you can delete this one with `efibootmgr` but is no problem if you leave this installed.

you can check your boot entries in your system with:

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

and after this, check `man efibootmgr`, and if you like, delete the boot entry that you are not going to use, the signed one or the normal one.